# Error for operations for Two Poisson distributions

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, error, error-propagation

Can error (std dev) in A +B or A-B be $\sqrt{A}$+$\sqrt{B}$ if A and B are Poissonian? If yes, what would be similar expressions for AB and A/B ?

Comment: $A/B$ is undefined.  In the other cases, please explain what you mean by "error:" we need some context to understand your question.

Comment: Question editied

Comment: As said by @whuber X/Y is only defined for Y distributed as a truncated Poisson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda)$ and you have random observations $X_1, \dots, X_n,$
then $T = X_1 + \cdots + X_n \sim \mathsf{Pois}(n\lambda).$
If your goal is to make confidence intervals, then the following
may be relevant for making CIs for Poisson means.

> The logic is somewhat similar that of the Agresti-Coull binomial 95% CI based on $\hat p = (x+2)/(n+4)$ with standard error
> $\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)/(n+4)},$ which is superior to the Wald CI
> based on $\hat p = x/n$ with standard error $\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)/n}.$

If $\lambda$ is not too small, a reasonable 95% CI for $n\lambda$
is of the form $T+2 \pm 1.96\sqrt{T+1}.$ Divide endpoints by $n$
to get a CI for $\lambda.$ For the case $n=10, \lambda=5$ with
data simulated below in R, the 95% CI for $\lambda$ is
$(2.86, 5.34).$

```
set.seed(2020)
lam = 5; n = 10; pm=c(-1,1)
t = sum(rpois(n, lam));  t
t
[1] 39
CI = t+2 + pm*1.96*sqrt(t+1)
CI.lam = CI/n;  CI.lam
[1] 2.860387 5.339613
```

I suppose that a CI for the difference in two Poisson means
could be arise from inverting the test of $H_0: \lambda_1=\lambda_2$ against $H_a: \lambda_1 \ne \lambda_2.$

If you can give us some idea what you intend to do with the product of two
Poisson random variables, maybe one of us can give a useful
response. If you're interested in a CI, maybe the appropriate standard error could come from bootstrapping.

*Note:* With $n=10,\lambda=4,$ the style of CI suggested above for $\lambda$
has about 95% coverage probability based on a million
such 95% CIs.

```
set.seed(808)
t = rpois(10^6, 10*4)
ucl = (t+2 + 1.96*sqrt(t+1))/10
lcl = (t+2 - 1.96*sqrt(t+1))/10
mean(lcl <= 4 & ucl >= 4)
[1] 0.952753
```

Comment: I have been thinking about products of Poissons, but plan to post nothing here unless you say what application and type of analysis _you_ have in mind. Why do you want to know standard error? No use writing up stuff of unpredictable value.

Comment: I was working on GRB data and was trying to fit an exponential model to it. So, before that most of the data was just random noise, to I was trying to remove it by fitting a constant line to it, and removing all the data which has chi sq <=2. I was plotting a residual plot, which is chi-sq vs time since trigger(sec). So, for residual plots I want to fit with error bars, for which I need this y= u/v since chi-sq = (model-data)^2/err^2, where err= sqrt(data) corresponding to each point.